# What is the name of the pump that goes in the drain between a washing machine and the sewer?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, terminology

My washing machine drains to a pump that then goes to the sewer.

What is the name of that type of pump?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "sump pump".

Comment: I'd recommend reconfiguring your drainage so that it doesn't need pumping... but I don't think that's the sort of recommendation you're looking for!

Comment: I think the correct term would be "*drain pump*", "*basin pump*", or "*ejector pump*" if there's solid waste involved.

Comment: @Tester101 I think that's the answer

Comment: @Tester101: If there's "solid waste" in the output of your washing machine, it probably needs to be repaired :-)

Comment: @DaveTweed I agree, but the washer *may* not be the only fixture using drain.  I'm just covering all the angles.

Answer (score 1):

Ejector pump. If your washer is in the basement and the sewer is overhead, gravity drain won't work.